# .htaccess redirect 301 http to https -sub directory- what is better ? and why?

Tags: .htaccess

i want to redirect (301) sub directory in my site from http to https

lets say this is the domain `www.example.com`
and this is the sub directory `www.example.com/games`

which option is better from those :

1. put this code inside the .htaccess file inside the directory

   ```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
   ```
2. put this code in the .htacces file in the main site:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} games
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
   ```

and if you can please tell me why ?
which is faster for the host ?

and if the answer is the same if the sub directory is like this : `games.example.com?`

thanks !

Comment: If you have a separate htaccess file in the `games` directory then your server will only read `/games/.htaccess` to process the subdirectory URL. Your root htaccess doesn't serve your `/games/` URLs.

Comment: @AmitVerma Sorry, but that is not true. Of course the http server will also consider a potential configuration file located in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, even if there is another one in a folder beneath it. The question indeed is where this shown configuration file is located, but others certainly will also get evaluated, if they exist and are readable for the process.

Comment: so what is the answer ? where is the best place to put this redirect rules?